# App crash on AppIndexing crawl

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

We noticed a spike in app crashes in our android crash reporting tool. It started happening about a week ago (on January 7). Device experiencing the crashes is reported as Calypso AppCrawler  running Android 4.4.4 (eng.hendriks.20151229.110347).

Here is stack trace:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.app.package.here.Module$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideApplicationProvidesAdapter"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file
>   "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.google.android.apps.appcrawler.espressocrawler-1.apk",
>   zip file
>   "/data/app/com.app.package.here-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.android.apps.appcrawler.espressocrawler-1,
>   /data/app-lib/com.app.package.here-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass()(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass()(ClassLoader.java:497) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass()(ClassLoader.java:457) at
>   com.app.package.here.Module$$ModuleAdapter.getBindings()(Module$$ModuleAdapter.java:31)
>   at
>   com.app.package.here.Module$$ModuleAdapter.getBindings()(Module$$ModuleAdapter.java:16)
>   at
>   dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.makeGraph()(ObjectGraph.java:185)
>   at
>   dagger.ObjectGraph$DaggerObjectGraph.access$000()(ObjectGraph.java:138)
>   at dagger.ObjectGraph.create()(ObjectGraph.java:129) at
>   com.app.package.here.Application.buildObjectGraphAndInject()(Application.java:247)
>   at com.app.package.here.Application.onCreate()(Application.java:126)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()(Instrumentation.java:1007)
>   at
>   android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate()(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:323)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication()(ActivityThread.java:4328)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500()(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage()(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage()(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop()(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main()(ActivityThread.java:5001) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative()(Method.java:-2) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main()(ZygoteInit.java:601) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main()(NativeStart.java:-2)

It doesn't seem to affect any of our users, but clearly there is something going wrong here. I wonder if anyone had experienced the issue before? Any workarounds, fixes?

Comment: Still suffering from this problem? Could you provide more information? What does the DC reports say about it?